# Accounts.createUser() is returning undefined on client

Tags: meteor

I have a SignUp/SignIn Process on my meteor site. I have a form to register new users and a form to login users.

I init users on `serverside` via

```js
Accounts.createUser({username: "myusername", password: "mypassword"});
```

and I can login into my dummyusers via my loginform on the `client` with

```js
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password)
```

I dont know why but for some reason I can´t create new users on clientside. If I call

```js
Accounts.createUser({username: username, password: password});
```

it returns `undefined` (safari)

I checked the input strings (username, password) and its not generating the error even pure strings like

```js
Accounts.createUser({username: "test", password: "pass"});
```

returns `undefined` on client console.

I published and subscribed my users via:

*Server*

```js
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
    console.log("Server Log: publishing all users");
    return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

*Client*

```js
Meteor.subscribe("users");
```

I also can `count()` users on the client console but I cant use `Accounts.createUser()` so the createUser() function is not even working in my console.

Why I cant use `Accounts.createUser()` on `client/console`?

Comment: do me a favor, use this `callback function` to know where the errors come, `Accounts.createUser({username: username, password: password},function(error,result){if(error){console.log(error.reason}});`

Comment: funny error `Signups forbidden`. looks like some unused packages for accounts-ui (meteoric) were the problem. removed them. thx for the hack with the error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Accounts.createUser](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) is an asynchronous function on the client because it needs to query the server to know if it actually succeeded (the username or email could already be in use). The return value of an asynchronous function will always be `undefined`, so the result is expected.

If you start with an empty project and an empty database, you could do:

```js
Accounts.createUser({username: 'dave', password: 'password'});
```

which will return `undefined`, however a subsequent call to `Meteor.userId()` should return a string.

In order to determine if the call succeeded, you will need to supply a callback:

```js
Accounts.createUser({username: 'dave', password: 'password'}, function(err) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    console.log('success!');
});
```

Comment: I was looking for an example of how to do the callback when creating a user manually. Thanks.